# Несколько нюансов пунктуации при вводных словах

Tags: пунктуация

Возможно, наглость оформлять такое кол-во вопросов как один, но они объединены одной темой, поэтому я подумала: может, мне это сойдет с рук.

1. Союзы каких видов по характеру выражаемых ими синтаксических отношений и разрядов по значению, находясь в начале предложения, не отделяются запятой от следующего за ними вводного слова?
2. Согласно известным мне справочникам, вводные слова, стоящие перед сравнительным оборотом (с союзом как), целевым оборотом (с союзом чтобы), отделяются от них на основании общего правила. А происходит ли обособление вводных слов в положении после этих оборотов?
3. Цитата из справочника Лопатина: ***"Вводные слова и сочетания слов, стоящие на границе однородных членов или частей сложного предложения и относящиеся к следующему за ними слову или предложению, не отделяются от него запятой (вторая запятая опускается с целью указания на отнесенность вводного слова к последующей части предложения): Лось шел скачками в сторону озер, должно быть спешил на водопой (Пауст.); Послышался резкий стук, должно быть сорвалась ставня (Ч.)"***. Мне интересно: если вводные слова и сочетания в том же положении в предложении относятся к предшествующему им слову или предложению, они отделяются от него запятой (***лось шел скачками в сторону озер, должно быть, спешил на водопой***) или нет (***лось шел скачками в сторону озер должно быть, спешил на водопой***)?
4. Известно, что вводные слова, стоящие в начале  или в конце обособленного оборота, никаким знаком от оборота не отделяются. В справочниках это положение, как правило, сопровождается примерами оборотов, обособленных при помощи запятых.  В тех же справочниках сообщается, что  если вводное слово находится в начале оборота, заключённого в скобки, то оно отделяется запятой. А какой будет пунктуация, если вводное слово находится в начале или в конце оборота, обособленного посредством тире?

Буду признательна всем, у кого хватит терпения хотя бы прочитать мои простыни, не говоря уже о тех, кто найдет силы после этого ответить.

Comment: >Возможно, наглость оформлять такое кол-во вопросов как один,  
  
Дело не в наглости. Вы сильно ограничиваете возможность полноценного обсуждения.

Comment: Хорошо, порву вопрос на маленьких четыре). Но удалить этот я не уполномочена.

Answer (score 2):

1. ПРИСОЕДИНИТЕЛЬНЫЕ СОЮЗЫ И, НО, А, ДА ПЕРЕД ВВОДНЫМИ СЛОВАМИ. 
    Запятая обычно не ставится между присоединительным союзом и вводным словом,  так как  вводное слово тесно примыкает к союзу: 
   «И действительно, мы больше не встречались. И в самом деле, Гуд-Гора курилась. А впрочем, как вам угодно; выстрел ваш остается за вами. Да кроме того, выяснились и другие подробности дела. Но конечно, его трудно было переубедить».

Запятая ставится как исключение, когда требуется смысловое выделение вводного слова (авторский вариант): «И, как водится, вспоминали только одно хорошее. Но, к великой моей досаде, Швабрин, обыкновенно снисходительный, объявил, что песня моя нехороша».  Союзы И, НО в этом случае относятся к предложению.

1. ВВОДНЫЕ СЛОВА, ОТНЕСЕННЫЕ К ОБОСОБЛЕННОМУ ОБОРОТУ

А) Вводное слово, стоящее в начале или в конце обособленного ЗАПЯТЫМИ оборота, НЕ ОБОСОБЛЯЕТСЯ, так как  оно выступает В РОЛИ ПРИСОЕДИНИТЕЛЬНОГО СОЮЗА.  (В этом случае вводное слово и обособленный оборот  составляют единую интонационную фразу):
«Издалека, должно быть из железнодорожных мастерских, тоже откликнулись низкие гудки».
«Издалека, из железнодорожных мастерских должно быть, тоже откликнулись низкие гудки».

Б) При обособлении с помощью  ТИРЕ постановка знаков препинания НЕЗАВИСИМАЯ,  (В этом случае обособленный оборот имеет собственную интонацию второго плана, при которой возможно интонационное выделение ВВОДНОГО СЛОВА):
«Издалека, – должно быть, из железнодорожных мастерских – тоже откликнулись низкие гудки». «Издалека – из железнодорожных мастерских, должно быть,  – тоже откликнулись низкие гудки».

1. ВВОДНЫЕ СЛОВА, ОТНЕСЕННЫЕ К СРАВНИТЕЛЬНОМУ ОБОРОТУ

В начале сравнительного оборота вводные слова обособляются - так как у этих оборотов уже имеются СОБСТВЕННЫЕ СОЮЗЫ, им вводное слово в качестве присоединительного союза не требуется. Соответственно, вводное слово выполняют свою обычную роль:  «Всё это мне показалось странным, впрочем, как и другим».  В конце сравнительных и целевых оборотов вводные слова встречаются не часто, но, думаю,  их надо обособлять по той же причине: «Всё это мне показалось странным, как и другим, впрочем».

Comment: Ясно, спасибо. Таким образом, невыясненным остается только вопрос из 3-го пункта.

Answer (score 1):

~1. Не понял вопроса. Разве это от "вида союза" зависит? не отделяются союзы, которые относятся только к вводной части, но не ко всему предложению. Не могу навскидку сказать, насколько это правило абсолютно, но другого что-то и не припомню. Повторюсь, это если я правильно понял вопрос.

~2. и 3. Не понял разницы между 2 м 3. Тем более - в 3 пример совершенно непонятный. Вы же сами и приводите правильную пунктуацию у Паустовского, зачем еще что-то спрашивать? В любом случае слова "должно быть" относится ко второй части, поэтому второй запятой не требуется.

Что касается случаев, когда вводное относится к "предыдущему слову", то никаких изъятий из общих правил тут нет. Из классики сейчас не подберу, но вот, скажем, такая фраза: *"Я анализировал работу муниципальных служб в Лондоне, например, нигде ничего подобного не было"*. Вы об этом? Я думаю, что запятая нужна. Просто нет причин её опускать.

~4. Думаю - да. Скобки и парные тире в подобных конструкциях - знаки очень близкие, обычно даже взаимозаменяемые, поэтому и правила должны быть универсальны.

Comment: № 1. Зависит ли пунктуация от вида и разряда союза, мне неизвестно, поэтому я и задаю этот вопрос. Одни справочники утверждают, что запятая не ставится только после присоединительных союзов в начале самостоятельного предложения, другие распространяют правило на всю совокупность союзов.

№ 2 и 3. Разницы, может, и нет, но на всякий случай я решила включить в вопрос и 2-й пункт. Кому не трудно, тот прокомментирует.

Comment: № 3. Паустовский сомневался относительно целей лося, направлявшегося в сторону озер, и пунктуация дает нам это понять. Но потенциально в предложении может ставиться под вопрос направление движения животного(шел в сторону озер, а может, и не в сторону озер, а в сторону леса, например). Выделяется ли сочетание "должно быть" с двух сторон запятыми в случае, если относится к первой части? 

№ 4. Я тоже так думаю, спасибо.

Comment: >№ 3. Паустовский сомневался...  
  
Вы хотите сказать, что "Должно быть" в этой фразе может относиться к озерам?! *Лось шел, должно быть, в сторону озер?* - такой смысл, да? 
Крепко сомневаюсь в реальности, но если так, то запятая "должно быть", конечно нужна  А на основании чего её можно было бы опустить?

Comment: Да, вполне могло бы относиться к озерам, на мой взгляд. Я сомневаюсь, что запятая перед "должно быть" в этом случае нужна, по аналогии с тем случаем, когда "должно быть" относится ко второй части и запятая опускается во избежание двусмысленного понимания предложения.

Comment: И еще, по поводу первого пункта. behemothus, не затруднит ли Вас привести пример предложения, начинающегося с союза, который "относится только к вводной части, но не ко всему предложению". Просто я привыкла думать, что союзы, стоящие в начале предложения, служат для связи предложений в тексте, т. е. всегда относятся ко всему предложению.